# How to get the last quarter

Tags: go

Here below is my code to get the last complete quarter:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    layout := "2006-01-02T15:04:05.000Z"
    str := "2017-11-30T12:00:00.000Z"
    now, _ := time.Parse(layout, str)

    endDate := now.AddDate(0, 0, 0-now.Day())
    startDate := endDate.AddDate(0, -3, 0) // startDate is wrong: 2017-07-31
    // the following statement is needed to fix startDate
    if endDate.Month()-startDate.Month() == 3 {
        startDate = startDate.AddDate(0, 0, 1) // now startDate is correct: 2017-08-01
    }

    fmt.Printf("Start date: %v\n", startDate.Format("2006-01-02"))
    fmt.Printf("End date: %v\n", endDate.Format("2006-01-02"))
}
```

<kbd>[**playground**](https://play.golang.org/p/dXEd5o_BRn)</kbd>

Is there a better way to get the correct start date?

For instance, the last `startDate = startDate.AddDate(0, 0, 1)` statement has to be omitted if I want to get the last semester:

```
endDate := now.AddDate(0, 0, 0-now.Day())
startDate := endDate.AddDate(0, -6, 0) // startDate is correct: 2017-05-01
```

Why is there this difference?

Comment: I don't think that `if` statement is needed since `endDate` is always the latest day in the previous month. And `startDate` is `-3 months + 1 day` from `endDate`. [Check it out](https://play.golang.org/p/waPr8wlbiW).

Comment: You are right... but in case I want to get the last semester, then the last ‘startDate.AddDate(0, 0, 1)’ has to be omitted... and I don’t understand why - I’ll update my example in a few seconds.

Comment: You get date overflow, so maybe better solution would be to first get `startDate` and then set `endDate`, like this: [playground #1](https://play.golang.org/p/kPOgkt06Tn) or [playground #2](https://play.golang.org/p/LfutrQCi7_).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> [Package time](https://golang.org/pkg/time/)
>
> ```
> import "time"
> ```
>
> [func Date](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Date)
>
> ```
> func Date(year int, month Month, day, hour, min, sec, nsec int, loc *Location) Time
> ```
>
> Date returns the Time corresponding to
>
> ```
> yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss + nsec nanoseconds
> ```
>
> in the appropriate zone for that time in the given location.
>
> The month, day, hour, min, sec, and nsec values may be outside their
>   usual ranges and will be normalized during the conversion. For
>   example, October 32 converts to November 1.

---

For example, using normalization to get the last complete period (for example, quarter or semester):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func lastPeriod(t time.Time, period time.Month) (start, end time.Time) {
    y, m, _ := t.Date()
    loc := t.Location()
    start = time.Date(y, m-period, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, loc)
    end = time.Date(y, m, 1, 0, 0, 0, -1, loc)
    return start, end
}

func main() {
    layout := "2006-01-02T15:04:05.000Z"
    str := "2017-11-30T12:00:00.000Z"
    now, err := time.Parse(layout, str)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    const (
        quarter  = 3
        semester = 6
    )
    fmt.Println("Quarter:")
    start, end := lastPeriod(now, quarter)
    fmt.Printf("Base date:  %v\n", now.Format("2006-01-02"))
    fmt.Printf("Start date: %v\n", start.Format("2006-01-02"))
    fmt.Printf("End date:   %v\n", end.Format("2006-01-02"))
    fmt.Println("Semester:")
    start, end = lastPeriod(now, semester)
    fmt.Printf("Base date:  %v\n", now.Format("2006-01-02"))
    fmt.Printf("Start date: %v\n", start.Format("2006-01-02"))
    fmt.Printf("End date:   %v\n", end.Format("2006-01-02"))
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/0t4exjVgr-

Output:

```
Quarter:
Base date:  2017-11-30
Start date: 2017-08-01
End date:   2017-10-31
Semester:
Base date:  2017-11-30
Start date: 2017-05-01
End date:   2017-10-31
```